# Is it possible for a Chrome extension to communicate directly with a service worker?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'd like to show some metrics that are captured in the service worker code in my chrome extension.

I'm wondering if it is possible for a chrome extension to communicate directly with a service worker that is registed on the web page you are currently debugging?

The only way I can think of right now, is have my injected script use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/postMessage) from the page and forward the messages to my devtools extension but that doesn't seem very efficient.

A promising path was using the API [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/) and use the Chrome Devtools Protocol but the experimental [Service Worker part](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/ServiceWorker/) of the protocol is only available in the latest ([tip-of-tree](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/)) and this version can't be seem to be usable in chrome extensions.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: _"but that doesn't seem very efficient."_ - what makes you say that?

Comment: _"A promising path was using the API chrome.debugger and use the Chrome Devtools Protocol"_ - ...what makes you think using the Debugging API would be _more efficient_ than `postMessage`?

Comment: The most efficient method in Chrome would be to tempoarily add a web_accessible_resources iframe to the web page and then use it to *transfer* a port of MessageChannel as shown at the end of [this answer](/a/68689866), with the added steps of transferring one port to your devtools script via `navigator.serviceWorker` messaging and another one to the service worker of the page.

Comment: @Dai I was hoping there would be a way to communicate directly with the service worker rather than having the page in the middle forwarding messages to the service worker and the extension.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I'll try that.